# kivy чёрный экран

Tags: python, kivy

При запуске появляется только чёрный экран. Как это исправить?

оба файла находятся в одной директории

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

Window.size = (800,600)

class Body(Widget):
    def press(self, instanse):
        print('botton is pressed')


class KaApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Body()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    KaApp().run()`
```

Ka.kv:

```
<KaApp>:

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'horizontal'

    Label:
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
        text: 'loading...'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        
        Label:
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.8
            text: 'GAME'

        Button:
            size_hint: 0.6, 0.6
            text: 'Click me'
            on_realise: root.press
```

Comment: Класс Body наследуется от Widget но в коде я не вижу импорта или определения класса Widget.

Comment: Александр, спасибо, изменил

Comment: окей, я выяснил что это не просто чёрный экран, а экран на котором отсутствуют виджеты

Comment: попробовал определить kv файл даже через builder.load_file и builder.load_string, но это так и не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Вообще стоит почитать документацию по [kivy](https://kivy.org/#home).

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = '''
<KaApp>:

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'horizontal'

    Label:
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
        text: 'loading...'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
    
        Label:
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.8
            text: 'GAME'

        Button:
            size_hint: 0.6, 0.6
            text: 'Click me'
            on_press: app.run_game()
'''
root = Builder.load_string(KV)

class WeatherApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return root
    def run_game(self):
        print("Game!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WeatherApp().run()
```

Answer (score -1):

окей, я заменил *< KaApp>* в kv файле на *< Body>* и теперь всё работает